# Can't call a return value in Selenium Code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I faced an issue during writing automation test case - Selenium WebDriver (Java) that related to java experience where I have not much knowledge on it. So I need your suggestion to make it worked. I post all my code here, maybe it's long but helps to figure out my issue easier.

**I have 2 packages:**

- com.pack.setup + classA (to control web browser)
- com.pack.test + classB (to execute test case with a specific browser)

**CODE BELOW:**

**ClassA**

```
package com.pack.setup;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class classA {

    WebDriver driver;

    // Below is a constructor
    public classA (WebDriver driver) 
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception
    {
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {          
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://DOCs//SELENIUM PACKAGE//chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E://SOFTWARE//IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

**classB:**

```
import com.pack.setup.*;
public class classB{

    WebDriver driver;
    classA TC001 = new classA (driver);

    @BeforeMethod
    public void browserSetup(String chrome) throws Exception {

        // login access = new login(driver);
        TC001.setup(browser);

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "setTitle")
    public void addNewUser(String startHour, String startMin,
            String endHour, String endMin, String sTitle) throws Exception {


        TC001.login();
        TC001.addUser();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

- In test method (addNewUser) we can't use the driver that I expect to return from browserSetup after it calls the classA to setup.
- If I replace whole code that I wrote in classA (Method setup) into browserSetup (classB), it works.

So do I have anyway to not replace the code into classB but still have the driver returned back in my classB

Much appriciate for all your suggestions!

Comment: what is the `browser` variable?

Comment: Hi Saifur, in this case I put "chrome" as you can see. Actually I used parameter in TesNG to pass that variable.

Comment: I am not sure how you want this work for you. But, seems like you will get NullPointerException. You are invoking driver without instantiating this. I have an example for similar scenario [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/tests) which may help you

Comment: You're right. I got the NullPointerExeption. I can see [BaseTest ] and [ GitHubHomePageTests ] in in same package and the 2nd one extends the 1st one. I cut them down in 2 packages. I'll give a try to refactor my code like that to see how it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should read the guide [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks JeffC, I'll read the guide to get the idea and learn from that.